# WPF - ReSharper not recognizing inherited binding scope in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, resharper

I'm having trouble with ReSharper in the XAML design view. Here is my source code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>

            <!-- User selects item from list -->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Item}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.Resources>
            </ListView>

            <!-- Currently selected list item details are shown here -->
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Items}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </StackPanel>                       
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# Classes**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    // ...
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

ReSharper is underlining **Description** in `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>` in my `ContentControl` XAML element with the warning text of `Cannot resolve property 'Description' in data context of type 'MyNamespace.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel'`

I'm not sure how its getting confused because I specified my DataContext already in the `Window` element already so it definitely knows what class I'm working with. And my application runs without a problem and functions as expected so I'm certain it's a ReSharper issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, the Description Property can't be available in the DataContext of the MainWindowViewModel, when it is in a different class (/ namespace).
Try to set the DataType of the DataTemplate like this

`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Item}">`

Possibly you need to import the clr-namespace, but ReSharper should suggest the correct one if needed.

Comment: This fixed the issue! I realized that I specified `DataType` in my `ListView` but not in my `ContentControl` which explains why ReSharper was only complaining in the one place. Thank you!

Comment: @KyleV. Oh, I didn't see that you set the DataType in the Resource too, but it's needed anyway in the ContentControl.. no problem, your welcome (: